# How do you return the max of a column (Text field)?

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledb

I can not find a way to execute the following simple query:

```
SELECT max(@SomeCol) FROM test_table;
```

I can do just about everything else except for that, `max` doesn't return what I expect.

Comment: I'm not sure why you have the `@` in the column name.

Comment: What is the Max of "cat"?

Comment: Add more information on what max is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to workaround the  issue by loading the dB query/table into a .Net DataTable and use it's Compute method:

```
DataTable.Compute("AggregateFunction(DataColumn)", "condition|Nothing|null")
```

Comment: Hey thanks man!  That's exactly what I needed, Access is weird but man, thanks for the save.

Answer (score 0):

The question does not have enough information about @SomeCol's data type. Assuming it works for the numeric columns and your issue is just with text or string columns, then the order will be in ascii collating sequence order.

For an example if the table has the following values, then the returned max will be "Sridevi".

```
Name
====
Michael
Indra
Sridevi
Roger

select max(Name) from test_table;

MAX(Name)
=========
Sridevi
```

If you want to pick up based on the collating sequence, then use the following:

```
select SomeCol from test_table order by lpad( SomeCol, 2 );
```

Instead of 2, you can use as many characters you would like to use for collating sequence order. This example works for Oracle relational database.